# YouTube Monetization. Must i still pay tax even if I'm underage in South Africa?

Tags: taxes, south-africa

I live in South Africa. I make videos for YouTube and I haven't monetized my videos. I would like to, but I want to know whether I will be subject to taxation even if I'm underage (I'm 15 years old).

I want to know whether I will be taxed or not because of income received from overseas.

Comment: First make some money, then you can hire an accountant.

Comment: Is your government site page [Do I need to Pay Tax](http://www.sars.gov.za/ClientSegments/Individuals/Need-to-pay-tax/Pages/default.aspx) not helpful? I am in the US, but I think it's safe to say that regardless of age, there's a level of income that requires taxes be paid. There are child actors or entrepreneurs who make a small fortune. I doubt there's any country that exempts them until they are 18.

Answer (score 5):

The fact that you're a minor really only factors into who pays the taxes, you or your parents. If you are below the age where you can legally earn money (and therefore pay taxes), then the income will be considered your parent's or guardian's income, and they will be responsible for the taxes. If you are of the age where you are legally allowed to earn your own money, then yes, you will have to pay taxes. Either way, taxes must be paid. If age were a way of escaping the taxes, every big youtuber would simply open their account in the name of one of their children or a child they know...

Answer (score 0):

You will be liable to pay the tax

For the 2017 year of assessment (1 March 2016 - 28 February 2017)
if you earned less than R75 000 you will not have to pay any tax

The annual budget speach is this week and the new tax rates will be released but most likely that R75 000 will increase to R78 000+- so if you earn less than that tax would not even be applicable on you,

Should you earn in a tax year more than R75 000 then would be able to do your own tax return and payments via E-Filling on SARS's website : http://www.sarsefiling.co.za/

But if you earn less than R350 000 then you don't have to submit a tax return, but there is nothing that stops you from submitting one if you feel that you want to.

You can use https://www.taxtim.com/za/ to help you with other questions 
you might have.

You can potentially bring down your tax-able income by showing a loss in capital value of your equipment that you purchased that is now worth less than it was when you initially purchased it, but these are all things you should discuss with a tax practitioner, I am not entirely sure how you will show a loss in capital value as a sole-proprietor, that is what you will be since you are not a company.